# Python Textract form URL

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction

I am using [Textract](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) in python on a web server as part of an API. I want to post a url to the server with a url and have textract extract text from that url (eg http://www.sample-videos.com/pdf/Sample-pdf-5mb.pdf)

I get a 502 proxy error in response when I try to post and my python log shows

> textract.exceptions.MissingFileError: The file "http://www.sample-videos.com/pdf/Sample-pdf-5mb.pdf" can not be found.

Is this because Textract can't extract from remote files and if so, is there a work around?

Thanks!

Comment: Is Textract meant to be able to download from a website? I imagine you have to do that first with [something like `urllib`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

Comment: Thanks Peter I think Textract can only process local files and urllib pointed me down the right road. I will add an answer with my code.